# Почему O(n!) медленнее O(n^2)?

Tags: алгоритм

Изучаю пособие "Грокаем Алгоритмы", здесь написано следующее:

> O(n!). Пример: очень медленные алгоритмы.
> O(n^2). Пример: медленные алгоритмы.

Для себя решил проверить.

O(n!), n! = 3! => O(3!) = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6
O(n^2), n = 3 => O(3^2) = 3 * 3 = 9

Следовательно O(n!) < O(n^2)

Из сего можно сделать вывод: O(n!) быстрее, чем O(n^2)

Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: зря вы на `n = 3` остановились! Начиная с `n=4` факториал очень быстро обгоняет `n^2`. Например `10! = 3628800` - сравните это с `10^2 = 100` )

Comment: Если у автора вопроса 3 в квадрате будет 27 ( похоже на n^n) то с 10^10 проблем не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О большое - асимптотическое поведение функции при параметре стремящемся к бесконечности

конечно `n^2` на некотором участке больше `n!`, но при больших `n` `n!` значительно больше `n^2`

но опять же всегда есть свои тонкости:

например пример умножения матриц - классический способ имеет сложность O(n^3), а самый быстрый из известных алгоритмов имеет сложность O(n^2.3727) (Алгоритм Копперсмита — Винограда), т.е. лучше использовать последний алгоритм, как более быстрый

однако это именно ассимптотические оценки и скорости двух алгоритмов лишь пропорциональны данным степеням (3 и 2.3727), т.е. для первого алгоритма скорость может быть

```
v1 = 1000 * n^3
```

а для второго

```
v2  = 1000000 * n^2.3727
```

в итоге асимптотически более быстрый алгоритм почти для всех задач умножения матриц будет медленнее

например при сжатии jpeg выполняется много операций умножения матриц 8x8 и самый быстрый алгоритм - это классический O(n^3), причем алгоритм выглядит не как какие-то вложенные циклы от 0 до 7, а как 512 строчек умножения и сложения элементов массива (не рассматриваю конечно специализированные возможности современных процессоров)

чаше всего в алгоритмах та самая `n` довольно большая и поэтому можно ориентироваться на эту оценку, но иногда бывают и исключения

например: бинарный поиск по отсортированному списку имеет сложность `O(log(N))`, а обычный поиск по неотсортированному списку `O(N)`, то если у вас массивчик из 3 элементов, то никакого бинарного поиска не нужно - значительно больше работать будет

Comment: Вот просто шикарный ответ! Еще я бы привел в качестве примера то, что при малых размерах массива (от 3 до 8 элементов, навскидку) по времени выгоднее использовать сортировку пузырьком, чем quicksort

Comment: @S.H. обычно для малых размеров делают insertion sort (также как и для финальных разбиений quicksort) — но принцип абсолютно правильный. Подобный вопрос я часто задаю на собеседованиях кандидатам, многое показывает.

Comment: @AntonMenshov - а, если это можно рассказывать, не напишете ли, в какие проекты Вы собеседуете людей? Можно в личку: https://t.me/konst_dav А то я подыскиваю работу... - а, заглянул в профайл, понял, что вы в Канаде :-)

Comment: C `insertion sort` всё кудрявее: `quick sort` сортирует всё кроме подмассивов короче некоторой длины (16 или 32). Получается массив в котором все элементы лежат не далеко от своих мест. Затем на этом массиве целиком запускается вариант `insertion sort`, который на таком массиве гарантировано за 16 или 32 прохода завершает сортировку.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что значок O() обозначает "асимптотически".

То есть, чтобы понять, почему O(n!) медленнее O(n^2), надо написать рядом несколько значений каждой из функций:

```
    n        n!          n^2
    1        1           1
    2        2           4
    3        6           9
    4        24          16
    5        120         25
    6        720         36
    7        5040        49
    8        40320       64
    9        362880      81
    10       3628800     100
```

Так понятнее?

PS. А книжка - да, прикольная. Особенно приятно, что она объясняет алгоритмы типа BFS простыми словами, без лишнего заморачивания головы

Comment: А ещё формула Стирлинга. A ещё `n^a = o(b^n)`. В общем показательная функция обгоняет любой многочлен.